# Is it offensive to call a redhead a "ginger"?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, slang, pejorative-language, offensive-language

So I just re-watched [this great comedy by Tim Minchin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVN_0qvuhhw), and here are the questions:

1. How bad/offensive is the g-word
   really (other than being an anagram of the n-word)?
2. What are alternatives? Is "redhead"
   more appropriate?

Comment: In Australia the term "ranga" is becoming more and more common. Short for "orangutan", I think it might be a *wee* bit more offensive than "ginger". :)

Comment: Off topic a bit - in Scotland its pronounced 'Ginga' - rhymes with 'singer'

Comment: Um, *singer* doesn't rhyme with *ginga*. It does rhyme with *ginger*, however.

Comment: Only if you live in the West Midlands, UK ;-)

Comment: @Martha: Pronounced: GING-A, slang variant widely used in the UK.

Comment: @Matt - that was the first word that came to my mind

Comment: @Martha - living in the USA doesn't make you omniscient ;-)

Comment: @5arx: I was just sayin'. :p

Comment: @Martha - perhaps we should push for a sister site - americanEnglish.stackexchange.com ?  ;-)

Comment: The phenomenon of "Only a X can call another X X" is called [N Word Privileges](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NWordPrivileges) by tv tropes.

Comment: Nobody in the US who isn’t an anglophile would recognize *ginger* as synonymous with *redhead(ed)*. At most, it seems rather weird and silly to us. It certainly doesn’t come across as pejorative or offensive.

Comment: @tchrist many Americans became familiar with the term *ginger* via the South Park episode “Ginger Kids”, which originally aired on Nov. 9, 2005.

Comment: @tchrist I don't know what you're talking about.  Everyone I know is familiar with that meaning, including people across the country.

Comment: I've only ever used "ginger" for cats. I can't imagine calling someone "ginger" is any more offensive than calling someone "blonde", though.

Comment: Considering all the kerfuffle in America about the word *niggardly*, it wouldn't surprise me to learn that some people see *ginger* as a thinly-disguised offensive anagram.

Comment: How about *copper top*?

Comment: I am ginger, not offended by the word. Do blondes get offended by being called blonde when "fair haired" is seen as a more positive term? It is more the fact that gingers are singled out as different because only 1-2% of the human population (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hair) are considered red headed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be getting more offensive, and the amount of offence caused seems to be geographic. I think the offence really depends where you are in the world.

After that, it's quite a subjective question.

Here in the UK, it's still quite widely used, but politicians / celebrities that use the phrase (or phrases like it) get criticised. The criticism isn't enough to get someone fired, but an apology is probably needed.

See the recent news article about [Harriet Harman calling someone a ginger rodent](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-scotland-politics-11658228).

BTW, there's also a fair bit of pushback against how offensive the use of ginger is in comparison to other racial slurs. There's no history of slavery associated with red hair, and this fact is increasingly mentioned in conversations about "ginger".

I don't think this gets to the root (ha) of the issue here in the UK though. Ginger hair is associated with the underclasses. If that association gets stronger, then maybe the word will be seen as being more offensive.

I think the best I can give you is "We'll see".

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this is pretty much restricted to the UK. In the US, the first thing that springs to mind upon hearing the word "ginger" is the spice (mmm... gingersnaps...). The "redhead" meaning is pretty far down the list, and the concept that this could somehow be derogatory is a bit, um, alien.

Comment: I'll second Martha's point, and note that the only time I've heard the term ginger used to refer to a redhead in the US was in the show SouthPark.  All other occurrences have been UK-based people/shows.

Comment: Perhaps I don't get out enough, but this is the first time I have _ever_ encountered the suggestion that there might be anything derogatory about the word 'ginger' in any context. I am in the UK.

Comment: As a "ginger" UK person. There is a bit of an issue with it, but then there always has been, it goes back centuries if not millennia.  Last bastion of acceptable racism.

Comment: @Orbling: AFAIK, "ginger" is not a race, so *racism* isn't the right word.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: In the UK, the majority of the redheads descend from the Picts and the Danes I believe, so that would constitute hereditary inheritance of a physical attribute.  It is as much a race as "black" is (as opposed to African-origin), that is readily accepted as such.  Prejudice against a genetically inherited feature at any rate.

Comment: @seanyboy - reminds me of (untrue) stories circulating the internet that red hair is about to die out http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/life/genetic/redhead-extinction.htm

Comment: @Orbling: Other genetically inherited traits include height, colour of eyes, and baldness. And yet I don't think you'd call discrimination against short people "racism". Race doesn't actually exist when you look at it closely, of course, but I disagree that even within the conventional loose definitions, redheadedness "is as much a race as" 'black' (which I don't think is a race either).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I agree with your point on the definition of race.  Physical attributes do not, a race, make.  However there is a link, the skin colour discrimination comes with an assumption on ethnicity, as does hair colour.  I get called Irish (in a manner somehow supposed to give offence) because of my hair colour.  Odd when you consider that it is more common in Scotland, and I am neither. :-/

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Additionally, height, eye colour and baldness, do not particularly invoke a particular region or ethnicity.  Whereas skin colour and redheadedness do - that is what gives them a racial component.

Comment: " Ginger hair is associated with the underclasses." - Is it? Never heard of that before.

Comment: Hmm, actually I think there IS a certain amount of slavery associated with red hair: red hair is generally associated with the Irish and the Scots, and both groups were oppressed by the English. The Irish in Britain were oppressed more recently than blacks, I think. Whether that history comes to people's minds when someone says "ginger" I have no idea. As others have noted, as an American I have only heard the word from UK sources.

Answer (score 14):

> Is it offensive to call a redhead a “ginger”?

Yes, quite possibly, but the offensive word isn't *ginger*, it's *a*.

If you say *He's ginger.* you're describing a distinctive physical feature.  Useful if you want to recognise him on your blind date.

If you say *He's a ginger.* you're suggesting that his gingerness is his most important quality.  This is rarely helpful and, in light of the recent spate of gingers-have-no-friends jokes, best avoided.

If you say *He's a “ginger”.* with quotes around the word ginger ... well ... that's just off the scale!  ;-)

Of course, context is everything:

- *For our April issue, I think we should use the ginger for the front cover and the blonde for the centrefold.*

OK

- *I thank the ginger delegate for the interesting points he raised about the Child Poverty Action Plan.*

facetious

Comment: Same difference between “He's gay” (perfectly fine) and “He's a gay” (excuse me?! \*thwack\*).

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for the question, I think it's a good one.  Here's what I think:

1. Alternatives:  "Redhead" is right, I think - it seems to be the analogue of "blonde" or "brunette".  What you'd be looking for is a straightforward descriptive term, and that would be it.  A term like "ranga" obviously has a large (derogatory) evaluative (value judgment) flavour to it: "you've got red hair, and that's a bad thing"; which is obviously the analogue of "you've got black skin, and that's a bad thing."
2. If you follow such an analysis then there is still a case for considering "ginger" to have a strong evaluative flavour. The usage I'm familiar with is "he/she *is a ginger*" and almost never "he/she *has ginger hair*."  So the implication is a conceptual reduction of the person to "a ginger" rather than someone "with ginger hair".  It says "what you are is a ginger."  Like saying someone is "a black", and defining *what they are* by the colour of their skin.  Of course, on the same analysis, "ranga" is a terrible word - which is indeed common currency here in Australia (like "bunga", for the indigenous).

But certainly, context is important.  As someone mentioned, the history of oppression of darker skinned races makes discriminating along those lines much more severe than discrimination along the lines of hair colour.  Still, the analogy between the two is pretty significant.  I would certainly never use the word...

Comment: +1 Very good point on the discrepancy between stating a feature and *becoming* that feature.

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been mentioned earlier here, but in the US people really do not use the word "ginger" to describe a person with red hair; that word  only became known to Americans  because of Harry Potter so it is fairly recent (Trey Parker and Matt Stone ruthlessly capitalized upon it in **South Park**, but it was around before that thanks to Rowling's books: they did not edit it in the US edition.) More commonly on this side of the pond you'd hear the phrase "carrot top" or ”Titian haired” to describe a redhead, and neither are pejorative.

Another favorite American term is ”firecrotch”, but this term subscribes more to an old cultural belief that redheads are sexy, wild, and vivacious (you'd say it to your lover to flirt or talk dirty; whatever else it should NEVER be directed at someone else's mate lest said mate try to rip you to shreds.)  For decades,  in stark contrast to the UK stigma, the smoking hot redhead has been a staple of American movies, comics, and cartoon for generations. Jessica Rabbit, Christina Hendricks, Poison Ivy, Rita Hayworth, Ariel the Mermaid, Nicole Kidman: they are proof Americans worship fiery locks (Jessica Rabbit's sizzling rendition of *Why Don't You Do Right?* launched many a young American lad into puberty and 20 years later their adult selves still peek at it, drooling.) Several Hollywood actresses have payed thousands of dollars to get that coppery cascade of curls, among them Amy Adams and Emma Stone, and lately the boys have been getting in on the action: one of the sexiest men in Hollywood right now is Damian Lewis, who women swoon over.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use of the term ginger is offensive. As a natural redhead, I am highly offended at the use of the word ginger, freck (referring to freckles), red, carrot top, ranga or any other term that people may come up with to refer to us.  Verbal abuse is never ok....

Comment: You're perhaps overstating the case: there are vast numbers of English speakers for whom the concept that *ginger* could be considered offensive is perplexing at best. You could improve this answer by stating where you live, in what contexts you have encountered clearly-offensive uses of this term, and how widespread that offensive perception is or was in those contexts.

Comment: Verbal abuse? Describing someone's hair colour is now verbal abuse? Oy vey…

Answer (score 2):

> So I just re-watched this great comedy by Tim Minchin, and here are
>   the questions:
>
> How bad/offensive is the g-word really (other than being an anagram of
>   the n-word)?

The word itself is not offensive. Unlike the N-word or the P-word, which are obviously meant to be abusive.

> What are alternatives? Is "redhead" more appropriate?

That would depend on the context. The only people that I have heard say "redhead" have been Americans. I haven't heard it used in the UK, because it's not necessary.

Pitarou and nulliusinverba made important points. The word ginger, can be offensive or not, depending on how it is used. If someone says that someone else is a ginger, that can be offensive because they are saying that the other person is just a ginger person. That they are defined by that. If you say that someone is ginger in the context of referring to them for some reason, there is no reason for that to be offensive. For example, if you are describing someone that you know, to someone else that doesn't know them, and you say that they are ginger, while describing them; there would be nothing wrong with that. It is just a statement of fact.

Basically, offensiveness will depend on how the word is used. There are certain people who make jokes about ginger people and use the word as part of insults directed at them. Just as there are people who do the same about blond people. That doesn't automatically mean that the word is offensive or that an alternative has to be used. That's like saying that the word *blond* is offensive and that you shouldn't say it. That would be ridiculous.

Also, it's not automatically offensive, because it's also used to describe a particular colour of some small cats. Like these: http://www.myfreewallpapers.net/nature/pages/ginger-cat.shtml

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_l4-QAyhv2Sc/S75Kz9KzABI/AAAAAAAAAEA/Ut8d8gXrq9g/s1600/ginger-kitten.jpg

Comment: All the ginger cats I have ever met have been enormous. Just saying.

Comment: They're great. Just for you Martha, there's a small one in the second link.

Comment: That's a kitten, not a cat.

Comment: Does it make difference? They are still the same kind of animal.

Comment: I guess I need to spell things out? You said *ginger* can be used "to describe a particular colour of some **small** cats" (emphasis mine). I noted that every ginger cat I've ever met has been enormous - in other words, "small ginger cat" is an oxymoron. However, all cats, even ginger ones, start out as small kittens, so your picture of an orange kitten is cute but irrelevant.

Comment: I thought the photo was relevant by being an example to make my point.

Comment: Most ginger cats I've seen in my life have been perfectly average-sized.

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, they're sometimes called bluey in an ironic fashion.

However, I've only heard Julia Gillard referred to as a ranga, not as a bluey. Maybe bluey is only used on blokes and not on sheilas.

Answer (score 1):

When I was in the reserves ten or so years ago, "Gingers" where about the only group that it was 'okay' to abuse after sexism and racism were (quite rightly) being stamped out. Not that it was really okay to pick on the redheads...

The thing is - any word can be used in a pejorative sense, and will eventually become offensive (another example - we now have SCOSA, because the word "spastic" went from being descriptive to pejorative to offensive).

Answer (score 1):

For me at least, I find 'ranga' extremely offensive because the only reason anyone would ever call someone a 'ranga' in the first place is if they *intend* to be offensive. 'Ginger' on the other hand only bothers my mum and I when people cleverly decide to spruce it up with unseemly post-additives.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that 'ginger' is about offensive as 'blonde' and for all the same reasons and in the same contexts. However, I'd further guess that there was a slight uptick in offensiveness when ginger started to be used as the first half of the rhyming-slang phrase 'ginger beer' to mean 'queer' which I first noticed in the late seventies.