# What's the perfect word that brings to mind a red-headed woman?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not talking an artificially-dyed Hollywood redhead, either. I'm looking for a word that perfectly recapitulates the kind of redhead who has lots of freckles, an extremely light complexion, and the kind of fiery red hair one would never mistake for the fake stuff.  Basically, the stereotype of an Irish lass (though I've read that in fact the proportion of redheads among the English is higher).

Comment: I would say that 'redhead' does a pretty good job of that...

Comment: Went searching for "natural readheads" for inspiration... *Not* a good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not a single word, I've seen **flame haired** used for this and unlike ginger its very unlikely to cause offence.

As you mention though, the hair colour is not enough to identify.

Another phrase I've seen for this very purpose is **Irish Rose** which I'd guess grew from the more common usage of *English Rose*.

Comment: The answer I really liked was "Irish Rose."

Comment: Unlike @Billare if don't think "Irish Rose" fits the bill at all. I don't think anywhere other than the US people would understand the image you were trying to paint. Scottish women are typically ginger haired and pale skinned, but Irish are Drak haired and green eyed. - Maybe you're mistaken for an Irish Setter?

Comment: I love the imagery of the rose though, it brings to mind delicacy.

Comment: Uh, yeah, there's a downside to the phrase [Irish rose](http://www.bumwine.com/wildirishrose.html).

Answer (score 1):

[***Ginger***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5060/only-a-ginger-can-call-another-ginger-ginger)

Comment: Though that is in the direction of reddish, it's definitely in contrast to red-head and certainly not bright red.

Comment: It is my belief that this is a discriminatory sobriquet.  The term is as offensive to red haired people as its anagram is to dark skinned people.

Comment: @chris, Offensive, yes, but not that offensive! (Which was the whole point of the song.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is Titian tressed hair.

> Titian is a tint of red hair, most commonly described as brownish-orange in color.[1] It is often confused with Venetian and auburn.[citation needed]
>
> **Etymology**
>
> The term originates from Titian, an Italian painter who would often depict women with red hair of this description. --[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titian_hair)

Comment: Can you explain why? Answers should be backed up by sources and details.

Answer (score -1):

We might see and say "Titian" but wrongly, I think, to describe your particular Celtic beauty.