# When did "blonde" become offensive?

Tags: word-usage, pejorative-language

The OED defines ***blond (noun)*** as:

> - A person with blond hair; one with light or ‘fair’ hair and the corresponding complexion; esp. a woman, ***in which case spelt blonde.***

> - ***1822*** Edin. Rev. 199 Brenda, the laughing blue-eyed blonde.

Other sources suggest that "blonde" as a noun should be avoided as it may sound sexist and offensive:

[Blonde](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/blonde_1):

> - *Blonde may be used to describe a woman’s hair, but it is sometimes considered offensive to refer to a woman as ‘a blonde’ because hair colour should not define what a person is like.* (OLD)

> - *The use of [blonde](http://grammarist.com/usage/blond-blonde/) as a noun in reference to a female with blonde hair is best avoided because it can be interpreted as sexist.* (The Grammarist)

Questions:

- When did the the noun  "blonde" acquire  a negative connotation"?
- Is it still nowadays better to avoid referring  to a woman as "a blonde"?
- Are there differences in this respect between AmE vs BrE?

Comment: It is no good looking in the OED - their most recent example of the noun *blonde* is from 1858. But yes, in Britain use of the noun *blonde* for a woman would be considered sexist in *correct* circles. A similar problem arises with the term *Essex girl*, which has come to imply far more than a girl who happens to live in Essex.

Comment: You should have provided examples of *blond/e* being used as an insult, or a derogatory term. Whether you believe it is more common in the US or in the UK. Do Italians ever suggest that blonde women are less intelligent than dark-haired women? Is this assertion only reserved in English speaking countries? You don't mention the most obvious derogatory expression: "dumb blonde". Blonde can also be a compliment "gorgeous blonde" "Blondes have more fun", "a blonde angel" etc. etc. This question has a lot of potential, just needs to be reworked.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Italian "bionda" does not carry the negative connotation that English dictionaries suggest http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bionda/. I am referring to "a blonde" without an adjective as it appears that you don't need one to look offensive or sexist. An adjective would modify (positively or negatively) any noun. A dumb brunette. But does "a brunette" sound offensive?

Comment: The expression "dumb brunette" I'd say is vanishingly rare. It's important to mention collocation, and connotations too. People also use the term  "a red head" but that is often seen as a compliment in the US.  Bob: "*I've been seeing a blonde for the last couple of weeks"* is demeaning for the woman involved, but I doubt that the person who utters this phrase is using "blonde" as a slur.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - you appear to suggest that "a blonde" is sort of neutral expression as in Italian. I think the term carries a different connotation in English, as suggested by usage reference above. Maybe it has lost some of its negative meaning in recent years? Why would OLD or the Grammarist make the comments cited above?

Comment: No, I'm saying it would have been better if you had given examples to support the dictionary's statement. See also Tonepoet's comment, which I've only read just now. He too mentions "dumb blonde" but also that "blondes" are often imagined to be beautiful.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Describing a woman simply as *a brunette* seems equally boorish to me. One is simply describing someone by one aspect of their physical appearance. Now if I describe someone as *An Italian linguist, with intelligence, charm and wit* - then that's a different matter.

Comment: Oops, it's spelt *redhead*, pardon me.  @WS2 Well, I can't find any fault in your logic there, I find myself to be in perfect agreement.

Comment: *blond was never offensive per se*. What an idea. It has been used in an offensive manner in the contexts everyone seems to have already mentioned. I refuse to bow to the PC POLICE. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Decades ago when I worked in Japan, an elderly Japanese colleague said to me, of a junior member of staff - "although he's a very tall man (no more than 6ft in his socks) he is very efficient". I was struck by the fact that in this man's estimation tallness was synonymous with awkwardness - rather a foreign idea to western society - but perhaps no more ridiculous than the "dumb blonde" idea.

Comment: Calling someone *a blonde* is reductive, but describing hair as *blonde* is not by itself the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

From [this Slate.com(1) article](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2010/10/when_did_blondes_get_so_dumb.html) titled "When Did Blondes Get So Dumb?"

> Probably since the late 19th century. In 1868, a British burlesque
> troupe began performing a spoof of the Ixion myth at the Wood's Museum
> theater in New York City. Featuring four blondes prancing around in
> tights, Ixion became an absolute sensation and outraged moralists who
> felt the girls were talentless wretches celebrated only for their
> bodies. The Ixion actresses were commonly referred to as the "British
> Blondes," but at some point in the ensuing decade, the term "dizzy
> blonde" started cropping up: slang for the sort of risqué stage
> performer that the Brits had helped make popular, and more generally
> for "professional" beauties, with "dizzy" meaning foolish or stupid.
> Hence in 1889 the Kansas Times and Star noted, "Many of the local
> clergy last night warned the church members against a 'Dizzy Blonde'
> company coming to one of the theaters soon
>
> (1) Slate is a daily magazine on the Web. Founded in 1996, it is a
> general-interest publication offering analysis and commentary about
> politics, news, business, technology, and culture.

*It's why artificial intelligence is a technique that consists of dyeing blond hair brown*.

Comment: Instead of saying from this "article" why not provide its name? Citations must be properly attributed. And I don't understand the last line, is that your comment? A brown-haired woman who changes the colour of her hair is called dumb because she employs "artificial intelligence" in order to achieve her aim?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I edited my answer - *Last line in one of the thousands jokes about "blondes"*.

Comment: Oh, it's a joke!? Not very good one. *Slate* magazine is very well known in the US and on the net. Christopher Hitchens used to write for it.

Comment: -1. While the last line of this answer is no doubt intended as a joke, **it's not funny, it's *offensive***. It's simply a reworking of the insulting and discriminatory proposition that people with a certain physical characteristic have lower intelligence. Substitute a nationality or racial description (or gender, or sexual preference, or religious group, etc) for "blonde" and the offence becomes obvious.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica It's a joke... nobody believes jokes... I remember those... in my day we used to tell them.

Answer (score 1):

In general, nouning an adjective runs the risk of sounding offensive. Compare "John is a gay" or "We have to make sure the gays like it too" to "John is gay" or "We have to make sure the gay customers like it too." So saying "She is a blonde" would be a little rude even if there was no insult associated with blonde-ness. But there is (as the other answer details) and so making it a noun is a bad thing.

This is not the same as "you can't say blonde". "I love how that sweater contrasts with your blonde hair" is fine between people who discuss appearance and clothing choices like that. "She looks amazing with blonde hair" is fine in contexts where your opinion on how she looks are ok, which isn't all of them. But calling someone "a blonde" is not that. Further, suggesting that a moment of bad judgement, forgetfulness, or distraction is "a blonde moment" or someone "being blonde" is offensive even when *blonde* is being an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

That is ridiculous. Blonde is not offensive and if we start treating it like an offensive word, it's going to offend me--someone who is blonde. It is factual and descriptive and there's no need to become overly sensitive all the time. Calling someone a "dumb blonde" is offensive because of the word "dumb." Furthermore, this is a silly trope constructed by movies and culture. We change it by just moving past it. And if someone wants to refer to you as "dumb," just find better friends. We don't have to tiptoe around these details and act like we're sensitive babies all the time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is a good answer in here but there's a lot of extraneous social judgement. See the varied answers at [Is it offensive to call a redhead a ginger](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5060/is-it-offensive-to-call-a-redhead-a-ginger). Though the answers there tend towards 'yes it's offensive', your answer is more likely, the word itself is not the problem it is 'dumb' or. the context that is offensive,  the word itself doesn't have the connotations. Also 'a ginger', a UK word, does have derogatory implications, whereas in the US 'a blonde' doesn't but is a bit old fashioned though.